# angular http post for image file to api return code 401

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

This is my angular code

```
let fileToUpload = this.profilePhotoFiles[0];
      let formData: FormData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);

      this._http.post('/api/Media/upload', formData , {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': fileToUpload.type,
          'Content-Disposition' : 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      })
        .subscribe(r => console.log(r));
```

This is how my api implement,

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("upload")]
        public IActionResult UpdatePicture([FromForm(Name = "file")] IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file == null)
                return StatusCode(500);
            //...............myUploadingCode
            return Ok();
        }
```

Url and Authentication are fine and correct. But it returns code **401** and can't get to API method `UpdatePicture`.
How can I solve it? What did I miss here?

**Edit**

This is how I get formData of uploaded photo

```
  let formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
```

**Update 1**

after `Authorization` header like

```
        this.headers = this.headers.append('Authorization', myTokenValue);
```

It passes `401 unauthorize` but it returns 415 unsupported formats.

**Update 2**

And after I added

```
        this.headers = this.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'multipart/form-data');
```

It passes code 415 but in API controller, but the parameter `IFormFile file` is null.

Reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55008484/1427849) question.

Comment: what happened when you try this API using postman ?

Comment: Are you using XSRF protection? It doesn't look like your sending that and asp.net will always return 401 from what I have seen

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda , it's same in postman. ( 401 )

Answer (score 0):

You should remove parameter in Web API and get image content by `Http` `Request` like this

```
            [HttpPost]
            [Route("upload")]
            public IActionResult UpdatePicture()
            {
                var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
                //Upload Image
                var file = httpRequest.Files["file"];
                //Create custom filename
                if (file != null)
                {
                }
                if (file == null)
                    return StatusCode(500);
                //...............myUploadingCode
                return Ok();
            }
```

Also dont need pass your header.

```
this._http.post('/api/Media/upload', formData , {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': fileToUpload.type,
          'Content-Disposition' : 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      })
```

change to

```
this._http.post('/api/Media/upload', formData)
```

Comment: same , 401 again . Can't reach to `UpdatePicture()` .
And also , HttpContext doesn't have `Current`

Answer (score 0):

Please delete below line and try again :

`'Content-Type': fileToUpload.type,`

Client side :

```
let fileToUpload = <File>files[0];
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);

this.http.post('YourURL', formData, {headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',     
  'Content-Disposition' : 'multipart/form-data'
},reportProgress: true, observe: 'events'})
  .subscribe(event => {
    ....
  });
```

Then server side will be :

```
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public IActionResult Upload([FromForm(Name = "file")] IFormFile file)
{


}
```

Another way is fetch the file from `Request.Form` . Client side :

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);

this.http.post('https://localhost:5001/api/upload', formData, {reportProgress: true, observe: 'events'})
.subscribe(event => {
    if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
    this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
    else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
    this.message = 'Upload success.';
    this.onUploadFinished.emit(event.body);
    }
});
```

Server side :

```
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public IActionResult Upload()
{
    try
    {
        var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
        var folderName = Path.Combine("StaticFiles", "Images");
        var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);

       .....
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       ....
    }
}
```